# Fetch all records from WatermelonDB database

Tags: database, react-native, sqlite, watermelondb

I would like to know why is the following block of code is returning the whole database object?

```
const getChatListFromDatabase = async () => {
    try {
      const chatList = await database.collections
        .get("chatList")
        .query()
        .fetch();
      return chatList;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // prettier-ignore
    (
     async () => {
      const list = await getChatListFromDatabase();
      console.log("the list is : ", list)
      }
    )()
  });
```

The chatlist and the list contain the database object instead of all the records.
I would like to know if I am writing the query wrong or something else is there that is being missed by me.

Following is the returned object by the query:

```
the list is :  Array [
  ChatListModel {
    "__changes": BehaviorSubject {
      "_value": [Circular],
      "closed": false,
      "hasError": false,
      "isStopped": false,
      "observers": Array [],
      "thrownError": null,
    },
    "_isEditing": false,
    "_preparedState": null,
    "_raw": Object {
      "_changed": "",
      "_status": "created",
      "email": "qwe@asd.com",
      "id": "j9lumqrj3cf5usat",
      "lastMessage": "bro this works",
      "messageStatus": "sent",
      "profileImageUrl": "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/86/6f/2e/866f2ec93c7c05560a76fbbbc470e161.jpg",
      "time": "12:34",
      "userId": "62041ac4cb15d7549f0e61f7",
      "username": "qwe",
    },
    "_subscribers": Array [],
    "collection": Collection {
      "_cache": RecordCache {
        "_debugCollection": [Circular],
        "map": Map {
          "j9lumqrj3cf5usat" => [Circular],
        },
        "recordInsantiator": [Function anonymous],
        "tableName": "chatList",
      },
      "_subscribers": Array [],
      "changes": Subject {
        "closed": false,
        "hasError": false,
        "isStopped": false,
        "observers": Array [],
        "thrownError": null,
      },
      "database": Database {
        "_isBeingReset": false,
        "_isBroken": false,
        "_resetCount": 0,
        "_subscribers": Array [],
        "_workQueue": WorkQueue {
          "_db": [Circular],
          "_queue": Array [],
          "_subActionIncoming": false,
        },
        "adapter": DatabaseAdapterCompat {
          "underlyingAdapter": SQLiteAdapter {
            "_dbName": "dbHello",
            "_dispatcher": SqliteNativeModulesDispatcher {
              "_tag": 1,
            },
            "_dispatcherType": "asynchronous",
            "_initPromise": Promise {
              "_U": 0,
              "_V": 1,
              "_W": undefined,
              "_X": null,
            },
            "_migrationEvents": undefined,
            "_tag": 1,
            "migrations": undefined,
            "schema": Object {
              "tables": Object {
                "chatList": Object {
                  "columnArray": Array [
                    Object {
                      "name": "userId",
                      "type": "string",
                    },
                    Object {
                      "name": "username",
                      "type": "string",
                    },
                    Object {
                      "name": "email",
                      "type": "string",
                    },
                    Object {
                      "name": "lastMessage",
                      "type": "string",
                    },
                    Object {
                      "name": "time",
                      "type": "string",
                    },
                    Object {
                      "name": "messageStatus",
                      "type": "string",
                    },
                    Object {
                      "name": "profileImageUrl",
                      "type": "string",
                    },
                  ],
                  "columns": Object {
                    "email": Object {
                      "name": "email",
                      "type": "string",
                    },
                    "lastMessage": Object {
                      "name": "lastMessage",
                      "type": "string",
                    },
                    "messageStatus": Object {
                      "name": "messageStatus",
                      "type": "string",
                    },
                    "profileImageUrl": Object {
                      "name": "profileImageUrl",
                      "type": "string",
                    },
                    "time": Object {
                      "name": "time",
                      "type": "string",
                    },
                    "userId": Object {
                      "name": "userId",
                      "type": "string",
                    },
                    "username": Object {
                      "name": "username",
                      "type": "string",
                    },
                  },
                  "name": "chatList",
                  "unsafeSql": undefined,
                },
              },
              "unsafeSql": undefined,
              "version": 1,
            },
          },
        },
        "collections": CollectionMap {
          "map": Object {
            "chatList": [Circular],
          },
        },
        "schema": Object {
          "tables": Object {
            "chatList": Object {
              "columnArray": Array [
                Object {
                  "name": "userId",
                  "type": "string",
                },
                Object {
                  "name": "username",
                  "type": "string",
                },
                Object {
                  "name": "email",
                  "type": "string",
                },
                Object {
                  "name": "lastMessage",
                  "type": "string",
                },
                Object {
                  "name": "time",
                  "type": "string",
                },
                Object {
                  "name": "messageStatus",
                  "type": "string",
                },
                Object {
                  "name": "profileImageUrl",
                  "type": "string",
                },
              ],
              "columns": Object {
                "email": Object {
                  "name": "email",
                  "type": "string",
                },
                "lastMessage": Object {
                  "name": "lastMessage",
                  "type": "string",
                },
                "messageStatus": Object {
                  "name": "messageStatus",
                  "type": "string",
                },
                "profileImageUrl": Object {
                  "name": "profileImageUrl",
                  "type": "string",
                },
                "time": Object {
                  "name": "time",
                  "type": "string",
                },
                "userId": Object {
                  "name": "userId",
                  "type": "string",
                },
                "username": Object {
                  "name": "username",
                  "type": "string",
                },
              },
              "name": "chatList",
              "unsafeSql": undefined,
            },
          },
          "unsafeSql": undefined,
          "version": 1,
        },
      },
      "modelClass": [Function ChatListModel],
    },
  },
]
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: have you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is expected to return data like that. Either use observable, or map your object. For example: create a method in your database model

```
 getChat(): ChatType {
    return {
      chatId: this.chatId,
      value: this.value,
    };
  }
```

After that map in your code like:

```
const list = await getChatListFromDatabase().map((item => item.getChat());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
try {
      const chatList = await database.collections
        .get("chatList")
        .query()
        .fetch();
      return chatList.ChatListModel.collection.database;
```

Comment: Not working, giving error:  "undefined is not an object (evaluating '_chatList.ChatListModel.collection')"

Comment: is this expected for the watermelondb returning a whole model object instead of the fields data?

Comment: Try something out. Different Collectionname and so on.